Interpreting GAM intercept (mccv's bam() function in R)
I am very new to GAMs (and, frankly, regression models in general), and I am struggling to understand the model summary I get when using the bam() function from the mgcv package in R, more specifically, what the intercept estimate represents.
My dataset contains pupil size data for an experiment where participants were exposed to linguistic stimuli in 1 of 4 "lang" conditions. The data were collected in 3 different locations. Each trial in the experiment lasted 3500ms, divided into 50ms time bins in the dataset. I am using the bam() function, because my dataset is rather large. "location", "lang", "Subject" and "Item" are factor variables. Pupil size and Time are continuous variables. Gaze coordinates are included to account for pupil size change based on gaze location.
I want to look at the changes in pupil size as a function of the interaction between language and location over the course of time. Subject and Item are included as random effects:
m1 <- bam(Pupil ~ lang * location + s(Time, by = location, k = 10) + s(Time, 
by = lang, k = 10) + s(Gaze_X, Gaze_Y) + s(Time, Subject, 
bs = "fs", m = 1) + s(Time, Item, bs = "fs", m = 1),
data = df, discrete = T)

Looking at the summary of this model I get the following:
Parametric coefficients:
                      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)              -113.5409    12.3626  -9.184  < 2e-16 ***
langEngNor                 13.0750     5.5122   2.372   0.0177 *  
langNNBM                   19.4937     1.4779  13.190  < 2e-16 ***
langNorEng                 -8.6308     5.5121  -1.566   0.1174    
locationNorth              29.3542    15.5140   1.892   0.0585 .  
locationWest               -8.7713    17.0011  -0.516   0.6059    
langEngNor:locationNorth   15.6711     1.9726   7.944 1.95e-15 ***
langNNBM:locationNorth     25.8995     1.9713  13.138  < 2e-16 ***
langNorEng:locationNorth   -0.5177     1.9737  -0.262   0.7931    
langEngNor:locationWest    15.9085     2.1683   7.337 2.19e-13 ***
langNNBM:locationWest      15.5085     2.1690   7.150 8.68e-13 ***
langNorEng:locationWest    20.6320     2.1707   9.505  < 2e-16 ***

As far as I understand, the intercept estimate (-113) is supposed to correspond to time bin 0ms, factor variables set to reference levels (location East, lang BMNN). The issue is that, judging by the plots, the pupil size never goes below 0 over the entire course of the trial (3500ms). So what does the intercept estimate mean here?
I would really appreciate any advice/information!

In a GAM, the intercept is not the expected value of the response when the smooth covariate takes a value of 0. In general, the intercept in a GAM fitted by mgcv is the mean of the response. The smooths are centred about the mean value. However, you have parametric factor effects, so the intercept will represent the mean of the response in the combination of reference levels of the factors only, not this combination when your continuous covariates are jointly 0.

I would drop the m = 1 from your two bs = "fs" smooths; these smooths are fully penalized so can shrink to zero (which is why m = 1 was suggested for these smooths in the first place).
Also, check that a Gaussian is a good conditional distribution for the positive continuous variable like pupil size; variables like this usually have a non-constant mean variance relationship and typically exhibit heteroscedasticity.
